# htaccess rewrite rule is not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

All,

I'm trying to redirect the hits via htaccess redirect scripts.

Below is my htaccess scripts.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^post/(.*)/$ post.php?tag=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ search.php?tag=$1 [L]
```

Issue : Index and search page are getting redirected. Post page is not getting redirected.

Please help on how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your root .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^post/(.+)$ post.php?tag=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^search/(.+)$ search.php?tag=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: This works great. But the code which was appearing in search.php?tag=news was good but search/news. It looks to be in very clumpsy. Any other settings need to be done?

Comment: Sorry didn't get, which rule is clumsy here? `search` rule is same `post` rule.

Comment: Not the rule. The page  search.php?tag=news was showing good but  search/news is not showing the pages correctly. I have verified the html and it looks to be the same.

Comment: That could be due to relative paths being used in css/js etc. Try adding  this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />` .

Comment: It is difficult to understand **not showing the pages correctly** error. Consider opening a new question for that problem and we'll help.

Answer (score 0):

Apache out of the box doesn't allow use of htaccess files. If you haven't edited your `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` file, you'll need to do so. Look for this chunk of code:

```
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            # Uncomment this directive is you want to see apache2's
            # default start page (in /apache2-default) when you go to /
            #RedirectMatch ^/$ /apache2-default/
    </Directory>
```

And change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`. After you've changed that, you'll need to restart Apache for the changes to take place (`service apache2 restart`).

**Caveat**

Most of what you'd want to do via htaccess files can be done more securely via the Apache configuration files (hence the htaccess files are ignored by default). See [this post](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingUseOfApacheHtaccessFiles) for details.